# How to make work ajax with the latest jQuery in jsfiddle?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

My [ajax jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/3RhE7/2/) doesn't work with the latest jQuery (1.7.2) but 1.4.x is ok. Using firebug I can see that the response is correct but the success was not fired.

Any idea how to make it work for the latest one?

```
function ajaxcall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            // 'html': button + script,
            'html': "test",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("ajax finished");
            $('#table').html(data);
        },
        dataType: 'text/html'
    });
}
```

final working version is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/3RhE7/3/)

Comment: use dataType as dataType: 'html' it will work, in your case you have declared dataType twic

Comment: Updated my answer with a working fiddle. I eliminated the `dataType` altogether, so...? Also, there is a five second delay on the arrival.

Comment: @Dhiraj: can you create an answer from your comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dataType: 'html'` should do it

```
function ajaxcall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            // 'html': button + script,
            'html': "test",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("ajax finished");
            $('#table').html(data);
        },
    });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/XUqTq/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought you would say that I had I used the dataType twice ;-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Here's a working version using `/echo/html/` and jQuery `$.ajax()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $button = $('#createissue');

    var test = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            type: 'post',
            success: show,
            data: {
                delay: 5,
                html: '<table><tr>' +
                    '<th>summary</th><td>This is a summary for an issue</th>'+
                    '<th>reporter</th><td>Christopher Robin</th>'+
                    '<th>assignee</th><td>Jared from Subway</th>'+
                    '<th>securitylevel</th><td>Hands in the air! Everyone is suspect.</th>'+
                    '<th>description</th><td>Something descriptive goes here, I suppose.</th>'+
                    '</tr></table>'
            }
        });
    };

    var show = function(table) {
        console.log(table);       
        $(document.body).append(table);
    };

    $button.click(test);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YCecC/1/

---

I knew I had one somewhere, but unfortunately I don't have a pure html version ready.

```
var test = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        success: show,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            delay: 5,
            json: JSON.stringify({
                summary: 'This is a summary for an issue',
                reporter: 'Christopher Robin',
                assignee: 'Jared from Subway',
                securitylevel: 'Hands in the air! Everyone is suspect.',
                description: 'Something descriptive goes here, I suppose.'
            })
        }
    });
};

var show = function(json) {
    var $row,
        $cell,
        rows = {};

    $tbody.empty();

    for (field in json) {
        $row = $tr.clone();

        $cell = $td.clone();
        $cell.text(field);

        $row.append($cell);

        $cell = $td.clone();
        $cell.text(json[field]);

        $row.append($cell);

        rows[field] = $row;
    }

    $tbody.append(
        rows.summary,
        rows.securitylevel,
        rows.reporter,
        rows.assignee,
        rows.description
    );

    $table.append($tbody);

    $(document.body).append($table);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YCecC/